# Mailer Generating Syntax Error: unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

I am trying to create a mailer (`ContactMailer`) from my `Contact` model, which saves information from a basic form to the database.  It is correctly saving to the database, but I'm getting an error for my mailer method.

It's calling `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.'`, highlighting the first `end` of my model code:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :send_contact_emails

  private

  def send_contact_emails
    for contacts do |contact|
      ContactMailer.new_contact(name, email, message).deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my `contact_mailer.rb` code:

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "geneticgolf@gmail.com"

  def new_contact(name, email, comment)
    @contact.name = name
    @contact.email = email
    @contact.message = message

    mail(to: "EMAILADDRESS@gmail.com", subject: "New Contact Us Submission from #{name}")
  end
end
```

Any help getting this working would be appreciated, as my extensive googling has not done the trick.

Comment: I suppose contacts is a collection of models, use `contacts.each do |contact|` instead of the given for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_create :send_contact_emails

private

 def send_contact_emails
    ContactMailer.new_contact(self).deliver_now 
 end
end
```

and:

```
 class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "geneticgolf@gmail.com"

 def new_contact(contact)
  @contact = contact
  mail(to: "EMAILADDRESS@gmail.com", subject: "New Contact Us Submission from #{@contact.name}")
 end
end
```

Comment: For both of these I get `undefined local variable or method 'contacts' for #<Contact:0x007fae9caa9450>`

Comment: you need to define `contacts` variable what you want to itarate

Comment: when you call `send_contact_emails` method pass the `contacts` variable to model

Comment: I tried changing it to `@contacts` which is defined in my controller, but I then got the error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: I was using a `before_save` method in my `contact.rb` model to call the `sent_contact_emails` method, not anything in either controller.  When I use the suggested `@obj.send_contact_emails(@contacts)` in my `before_save` method I get `undefined method 'send_contact_emails' for nil:NilClass`...did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: check it out i updated. any ways `contacts` is a attibute or not post some more codes

Comment: `self.contacts.each` gave me the same `undefined method 'contacts' for #<Contact:0x007fbf8438f428>` error I was getting previously, but trying `self.@contacts.each` yields an even funkier syntax error `syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '(' self.@contacts.each do |contact| ^`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113056/discussion-between-liz-and-pitabas-prathal).